# Azure Log Analytics - Alerts Advice

Tags: azure, alerts, azure-log-analytics

I have a question about azure log analytics alerts, in that I don't quite understand how the time frame works within the context of setting up an alert based on an aggregated value.

I have the code below:

```
Event | where Source == "EventLog" and EventID == 6008 | project TimeGenerated, Computer | summarize AggregatedValue = count(TimeGenerated) by Computer, bin_at(TimeGenerated,24h, datetime(now()))
For time window : 24/03/2019, 09:46:29 - 25/03/2019, 09:46:29
```

In the above the alert configuration interface insights on adding the `bin_at(TimeGenerated,24h, datetime(now()))` so I add the function, passing the arguments for a 24h time period. If you are already adding this then what is the point of the time frame.

Basically the result I am looking for is capturing this event over a 24 hour period and alerting when the event count is over 2. I don't understand why a time window is also necessary on top of this because I just want to run the code every five minutes and alert if it detects more than two instances of this event.

Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK you may use the query something like shown below to accomplish your requirement of capturing the required event over a time period of 24 hour.

```
Event 
| where Source == "EventLog" and EventID == 6008 
| where TimeGenerated > ago(24h)
| summarize AggregatedValue= any(EventID) by Computer, bin(TimeGenerated, 1s)
```

The '1s' in this sample query is the time frame with which we are aggregating and getting the output from Log Analytics workspace repository. For more information, refer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/query/summarizeoperator

And to create an alert, you  may have to go to Azure portal -> YOURLOGANALYTICSWORKSPACE -> Monitoring tile -> Alerts -> Manager alert rules -> New alert rule -> Add condition -> Custom log search -> Paste any of the above queries under 'Search query' section -> Type '2' under 'Threshold value' parameter of 'Alert logic' section -> Click 'Done' -> Under 'Action Groups' section, select existing action group or create a new one as explained in the below mentioned article -> Update 'Alert Details' -> Click on 'Create alert rule'.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/action-groups

Hope this helps!! Cheers!! :)

Comment: The query below works, in that I get a count of the events over the last 24 hours, the alerts insists on adding the bin function so would that be over 24h?

Comment: Event 
| where Source == "EventLog" and EventID == 6008 
| where TimeGenerated > ago(24h)
| summarize AggregatedValue= count(EventID) by Computer

Comment: Many thanks for your help on this, I will play around with different settings and see what results I get.

Comment: in this scenario, can we get the alerts based on the percentage of failures within a time frame says in 20 minutes, than the just calculation by counts

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question in the comments part, yes the alert insists on adding the bin function and that's the reason I have provided relevant query along with bin function by having '1s' and tried to explain about it in my previous answer.

If you put '1s' in bin function then you would fetch output from Log Analytics by aggregating value of any EventID in the timespan of 1second. So output would look something like shown below where aaaaaaa is considered as a VM name, x is considered as a particular time.

[image]

If you put '24h' instead of '1s' in bin function then you would fetch output from Log Analytics by aggregating value of any EventID in the timespan of 24hours. So output would look something like shown below where aaaaaaa is considered as a VM name, x is considered as a particular time.

[image]

So in this case, we should not be using '24h' in bin function along with 'any' aggregation because if we use it then we would see only one occurrence of output in 24hours of timespan and that doesn't help you to find out event occurrence count using the above provided query having 'any' for aggregation. Instead you may use 'count' aggregation instead of 'any' if you want to have '24h' in bin function. Then this query would look something like shown below.

```
Event 
| where Source == "EventLog" and EventID == 6008 
| where TimeGenerated > ago(24h)
| summarize AggregatedValue= count(EventID) by Computer, bin(TimeGenerated, 24h)
```

The output of this query would look something like shown below where aaaaaaa is considered as a VM name, x is considered as a particular time, y and z are considered as some numbers.

[image]

One other note is, all the above mentioned queries and outputs are in the context of setting up an alert based on an aggregated value i.e., setting up an alert when opting 'metric measurement' under alert logic based on section. In other words, aggregatedvalue column is expected in alert query when you opt 'metric measurement' under alert logic based on section. But when you say 'you get a count of the events' that means If i am not wrong, may be you are opting 'number of results' under alert logic based on section, which would not required any aggregation column in the query.

Hope this clarifies!! Cheers!!

Comment: I think I need something like Event 
| where Source == "EventLog" and EventID == 6008
| project TimeGenerated, Computer
| summarize AggregatedValue = count(TimeGenerated) by Computer
|  where AggregatedValue > 2

Comment: and to set to alert by number of results over one. I will play around with the settings.

Comment: I got that! So you can just create an alert by going to Azure portal -> LAWORKSPACE -> Monitoring tile -> Alerts -> Manager alert rules -> New alert rule -> Add condition -> Custom log search -> Paste below query under 'Search query' section -> Select 'metric measurement' under alert logic based on section and type '2' under 'Threshold value' parameter of 'Alert logic' section -> Click 'Done' -> Under 'Action Groups' section, select action group -> Update 'Alert Details' -> Click on 'Create alert rule'.

Comment: "Event | where Source == "EventLog" and EventID == 6008 | where TimeGenerated > ago(24h) | summarize AggregatedValue= count(EventID) by Computer, bin(TimeGenerated, 24h)"

Comment: Many thanks for your help on this, I will play around with different settings and see what results I get.

Comment: in this scenario, can we get the alerts based on the percentage of failures within a time frame says in 20 minutes, than the just calculation by counts